# Função Ajax executando várias vezes mesmo sendo chamada apenas uma vez

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Olá, estou tendo o seguinte problema: Tenho um modal que deve fazer a inclusão de um formulário no banco de dados. O botão submit chama uma função Javascript/Ajax, que por sua vez chama uma página php com a query. Até aí tudo bem, os dados são inseridos com sucesso. Mas na segunda vez que executo a função, ela executa duas vezes. Na terceira vez, três vezes. E assim consecutivamente. Tentei chamar a função através do action do form, através do botão submit e através da função onclick e obtive o mesmo resultado de todas as formas. O que pode estar ocasionando este problema?

Segue o código do modal

```
<!-- Modal Adicionar Item-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalItemAdd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addItemComanda" name="addItemComanda">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Adicionar item</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Código</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cod_item" id="cod_item" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" id="form_lista_prod">                          
                        <label>Selecione um produto</label>  
                        <input onclick="listarProdutos();" type="text" name="select_produtos" id="select_produtos" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o nome do produto" />  
                        <div id="listaProdutos"></div>  
                    </div> 

                    <input type="hidden" name="id_comanda" value="12">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Quantidade</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="qtde_item" id="qtde_item" value="1" required>
                    </div>
                </div>                
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancelar">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Adicionar" onclick="addItemCom()">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Segue o código da função:

```
function addItemCom() {
$('form').submit(function () {
    var dados = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'additemcomanda.php',
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: dados,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Teste dessa bagaça");
            $('#resultado').empty().html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});

$('form').trigger('submit');
$.ajax().empty();
```

}

E segue o código do php com a query:

`session_start();
include_once("config.php");
$idcom = $_POST['id_comanda'];
$cod_item = $_POST['cod_item'];
$nom_item = $_POST['select_produtos'];
$qtd_item = $_POST['qtde_item'];
if(!empty($idcom)){
    $result_usuario = "INSERT INTO PROD_COMANDA (COD_COMANDA, COD_PROD, NOME_PROD, QUANTIDADE, VL_UNIT, VL_TOTAL) VALUES ('$idcom', '$cod_item', '$nom_item', '$qtd_item', (SELECT PRECO FROM CAD_PROD WHERE CODIGO='$cod_item'), (VL_UNIT*QUANTIDADE))";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($mysqli, $result_usuario);

    echo $result_usuario;

}else{

    echo "Falha ao adicionar o item!";
}`

Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 1):

Colocando `onclick="addItemCom()"` no botão de submit, cada vez que a função é chamada irá criar na memória uma instância do evento `$('form').submit`, por isso está multiplicando o disparo do evento.

Não é necessário uma função pra isso, basta apenas o *event handler* com o id do form em questão:

```
$('#addItemComanda').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dados = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'additemcomanda.php',
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: dados,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Teste dessa bagaça");
            $('#resultado').empty().html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Veja que adicionei o `e.preventDefault();` para evitar o recarregamento da página (não precisa de `return false`).

Remova o atributo `onclick="addItemCom()"` do botão de submit.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas desta forma acabou não funcionando, aparentemente não chegou a executar a função. Também me preocupo se por acaso outros forms que eu venha a ter nesta página não podem acabar chamando a função desta maneira?

Comment: Coloque o id do form no seletor do evento: `$("#addItemComanda").submit`

Comment: Alterei a resposta com o seletor correto.